# Coordinates of WKT in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, coordinates, well-known-text

I have a table in PostgreSQL. And it has no X and Y coordinates. But, it has a geom column with the WKT. Also, I have created an empty column called LAT and other called LONG. So, what I want is to write the Latitude and Longitude of the WKT column for each point. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the geometry type? Can you give an example?

Comment: https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromWKB.html can create an instance of the appropriate geometry type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ST_GeomFromText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromText.html) function converts the WKT into a geometry object that PostGIS can understand:

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Lat = ST_Y(ST_GeomFromText(WKT_column)),
    Lon = ST_X(ST_GeomFromText(WKT_column));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column to store point geometry in your table e.g. "geom", then you can use the ST_MakePoint function. I suppose you have 2D geometry and you have the latitude and longitude in "lat" and "lon" column as decimal degrees. I supposed latitudes and longitudes are in WGS84 (SRID=4326). The following SQL command will update geom column:

```
UPDATE your_table SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lon, lat), 4326);
```

Comment: This is the solution to a different problem. The OP is trying populate `lon` and `lat` from a `geom`, though it isn't clear if the geometery is a "WKT" text string of just the presentation of a geometry as WKT from the client.  Either way, the solution would make use of `ST_X()` and `ST_Y()`, not `ST_MakePoint()`.